# Graphql Hasura Update if the field is not null

Tags: reactjs, graphql, hasura, graphql-mutation

I have a graphql type which I would like to update based on the value of one column.
For example the type has the following columns: id, col1, col2, col3 so I would like to update col3 if only if col1 has a value.
I am using react as frontend and HASURA as backend

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_is_null` statement to check if the column has a value or not:

```
mutation updateMutation {
  update_myTable(where: {id: {_eq: "id"}, _and: {col_1: {_is_null: false}}}, 
    _set: {col_3: "new value"}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```